# Building height query in ArcGIS JS API

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to do a building height query in ArcGIS JS API. When I slide the button according to height, I want to highlight buildings associated with height. How can I do that?

```
require([
    "esri/config",
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/views/SceneView",
    "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle",
    "esri/widgets/BasemapGallery",
    "esri/widgets/CoordinateConversion",

    "esri/Graphic",
    "esri/rest/route",
    "esri/rest/support/RouteParameters",
    "esri/rest/support/FeatureSet",
    "esri/widgets/Search",
    "esri/rest/locator",

    "esri/layers/SceneLayer",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "esri/widgets/Sketch/SketchViewModel",
    "esri/widgets/Expand",
    "esri/widgets/DirectLineMeasurement3D",
    "esri/widgets/AreaMeasurement3D",
    "esri/widgets/LayerList",
    "esri/widgets/Home",
    "esri/widgets/Editor",
    "esri/symbols/LabelSymbol3D",
    "esri/layers/support/LabelClass"



], function (esriConfig, Map, MapView, SceneView, BasemapToggle, BasemapGallery, CoordinateConversion,
 Graphic, route, RouteParameters, FeatureSet, Search, locator, SceneLayer, FeatureLayer, GraphicsLayer, 
 SketchViewModel, Expand, DirectLineMeasurement3D,AreaMeasurement3D,LayerList, Home,Editor,LabelSymbol3D,LabelClass) {

    // the layer where the graphics are sketched
    const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer({
    elevationInfo: { mode: "on-the-ground" },
    title: "Sketch GraphicsLayer"
    });

    esriConfig.apiKey = "AAPKf5c475a3978645a98668967366a26024mPzkb7hImO8bP4L5d0NOR0KEkZKgo43uf6wARoLkaCxI5DS9h6gBWpy7jfPvpaF3";

    const footprintBuildings = new FeatureLayer({
        url:
            "https://arcgis.geotech-company.com/server/rest/services/Hosted/Hacettepe_Buildings/FeatureServer",
        renderer: {
            type: "simple",
            symbol: {
                type: "polygon-3d",
                symbolLayers: [
                    {
                        type: "fill",
                        material: { color: [255, 237, 204] },
                        outline: { color: [133, 108, 62, 0.5] }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        
        visible: false
    });

    

    const extrudedBuildings = new FeatureLayer({
        url:
            "https://arcgis.geotech-company.com/server/rest/services/Hosted/Hacettepe_Buildings/FeatureServer",
        renderer: {
            type: "simple",
            symbol: {
                type: "polygon-3d",
                symbolLayers: [
                    {
                        type: "extrude",
                        material: { color: [222, 16, 16, 0.9] },
                        edges: {
                            type: "solid",
                            color: [133, 108, 62, 0.5],
                            size: 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            visualVariables: [
                {
                    type: "size",
                    field: "yukseklik",
                    valueUnit: "meters"
                }
            ]

        },

        popupTemplate : {
            // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
            title: "attributes",
            content: [
              {
                type: "fields",
                fieldInfos: [
                  {
                    fieldName: "{bina_adi}",
                    label: "Bina Adı"
                  },
                  {
                    fieldName: "{kat_sayisi}",
                    label: "Kat Sayısı"
                  },
                  {
                    fieldName: "{yukseklik}",
                    label: "Yükseklik"
                  },
                 ]
              }
            ]
          },

        visible: true
    });

    

    const map = new Map({
        basemap: "satellite",
        layers: [graphicsLayer,footprintBuildings, extrudedBuildings],
        ground: "world-elevation"
    });


    ///// label ekleme   

    let labelClass = new LabelClass({
        labelExpressionInfo: {
          expression: "$feature.bina_adi"  // Text for labels comes from COUNTY field
        },
        symbol: {
          type: "label-3d",  // autocasts as new LabelSymbol3D()
          symbolLayers: [{
            type: "text",  // autocasts as new TextSymbol3DLayer()
            material: { color: [ 0,0,0 ] },
            size: 15,  // Defined in points
            weight: "bold"
          }]
        }
      });
      // Add labels to the feature layer
      extrudedBuildings.labelsVisible = true;

      extrudedBuildings.labelingInfo = [ labelClass ];



    const view = new SceneView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,

        camera: {
            position: {
                x: 32.736299, //Longitude
                y: 39.850315, //Latitude
                z: 2400 //Meters
            },
            heading: 356.82,
            tilt: 55
        },
        qualityProfile: "high"
        
          
    });


    const polyInfos = {
      layer: extrudedBuildings,
      formTemplate: {
        // autocasts to FormTemplate
        elements: [
          {
            // autocasts to FieldElement
            type: "field",
            fieldName: "bina_adi",
            label: "bina_adi"
          },
          {
            type: "field",
            fieldName: "kat_sayisi",
            label: "kat_sayisi"
          },
          {
            type: "field",
            fieldName: "yukseklik",
            label: "yukseklik"
          }
        ]
      }
    };


    const editor = new Editor({
      view: view,
      layerInfos: [polyInfos]
    });


    const bgExpand3 = new Expand({
      view: view,
      content: editor
    });
    
    view.ui.add(bgExpand3, "top-right");


        
    ///// home buton
    const homeBtn = new Home({
      view: view
    });

    // Add the home button to the top left corner of the view
    view.ui.add(homeBtn, "top-left");


    //________________________________________________________________________
    var activeWidget = null;   //EKLEDİM

    view.ui.add("topbar", "top-left");  //EKLEDİM

//Layer List deneme _____________________________________________________________________
const layerList = new LayerList({
  view: view
});


//Expand layer list __________________________________________________

const bgExpand2 = new Expand({
  view: view,
  content: layerList
});

// Add the expand instance to the ui

view.ui.add(bgExpand2, "top-right");

//___distance ve measurement________________________________________

    document.getElementById("distanceButton").addEventListener("click",
      function () {
    setActiveWidget(null);
    if (!this.classList.contains('active')) {
      setActiveWidget('distance');
    } else {
      setActiveButton(null);
    }
  });

document.getElementById("areaButton").addEventListener("click",
  function () {
    setActiveWidget(null);
    if (!this.classList.contains('active')) {
      setActiveWidget('area');
    } else {
      setActiveButton(null);
    }
  });

function setActiveWidget(type) {
  switch (type) {
    case "distance":
      activeWidget = new DirectLineMeasurement3D({
        view: view
      });
      view.ui.add(activeWidget, "top-left");
      setActiveButton(document.getElementById('distanceButton'));
      break;
    case "area":
      activeWidget = new AreaMeasurement3D({
        view: view
      });
      view.ui.add(activeWidget, "top-left");
      setActiveButton(document.getElementById('areaButton'));
      break;
    case null:
      if (activeWidget) {
        view.ui.remove(activeWidget);
        activeWidget.destroy();
        activeWidget = null;
      }
      break;
  }
}

function setActiveButton(selectedButton) {
  // focus the view to activate keyboard shortcuts for sketching
  view.focus();
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  if (selectedButton) {
    selectedButton.classList.add("active");
  }
}

//_____________________________________________________________________________

    let type = "cartographic";
    document.getElementById("footprint").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        footprintBuildings.visible = true;
        extrudedBuildings.visible = false;
    });
    document.getElementById("extruded").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        footprintBuildings.visible = false;
        extrudedBuildings.visible = true;
    });




    //Toggle between basemaps
    const basemapToggle = new BasemapToggle({
        view: view,
        nextBasemap: "arcgis-imagery"
    });

    view.ui.add(basemapToggle, "bottom-left");


    // Buton_S____________________________________________________________________

    const bgExpand = new Expand({
      view,
      content: new BasemapGallery({ view: view,
        source: {
            query: {
                title: '"World Basemaps for Developers" AND owner:esri'
            }
        } }),
      expandIconClass: "esri-icon-basemap"
    });
    view.ui.add(bgExpand, "top-right");
    
    //___________________________________________________________________________________


    const search = new Search({  //Add Search widget
        view: view
    });

    view.ui.add(search, "top-right"); //Add to the map

    //route-----------------------------


    const routeUrl = "https://route-api.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World";


    view.on("click", function (event) {

        if (view.graphics.length === 0) {
            addGraphic("origin", event.mapPoint);
        } else if (view.graphics.length === 1) {
            addGraphic("destination", event.mapPoint);

            getRoute(); // Call the route service

        } else {
            view.graphics.removeAll();
            addGraphic("origin", event.mapPoint);
        }

    });

    function addGraphic(type, point) {
        const graphic = new Graphic({
            symbol: {
                type: "simple-marker",
                color: (type === "origin") ? "red" : "black",
                size: "8px"
            },
            geometry: point
        });
        view.graphics.add(graphic);
    }

    function getRoute() {
        const routeParams = new RouteParameters({
            stops: new FeatureSet({
                features: view.graphics.toArray()
            }),

            returnDirections: true

        });

        route.solve(routeUrl, routeParams)
            .then(function (data) {
                data.routeResults.forEach(function (result) {
                    result.route.symbol = {
                        type: "simple-line",
                        color: [5, 150, 255],
                        width: 3
                    };
                    view.graphics.add(result.route);
                });

                // Display directions
                if (data.routeResults.length > 0) {
                    const directions = document.createElement("ol");
                    directions.classList = "esri-widget esri-widget--panel esri-directions__scroller";
                    directions.style.marginTop = "0";
                    directions.style.padding = "15px 15px 15px 30px";
                    const features = data.routeResults[0].directions.features; //incele!!!

                    // Show each direction
                    features.forEach(function (result, i) {
                        const direction = document.createElement("li");
                        direction.innerHTML = result.attributes.text + " (" + result.attributes.length.toFixed(2) + " miles)";
                        directions.appendChild(direction);
                    });

                    view.ui.empty("bottom-left");
                    view.ui.add(directions, "bottom-left");


                }
            })

    }

    //coordinat gösterme fonksiyonu

    var coordsWidget = document.createElement("div");
    coordsWidget.id = "coordsWidget";
    coordsWidget.className = "esri-widget esri-component";
    coordsWidget.style.padding = "7px 15px 5px";

    view.ui.add(coordsWidget, "bottom-right");





  });
```

Comment: You have a lon of code, but no indication of what the problem is.

Comment: use an sql query similar to https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/query-a-feature-layer-sql/